# GCC 4.7 Source Character Encoding and Execution Character Encoding For String Literals?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, character-encoding, string-literals

Does GCC 4.7 on Linux/x86_64 have a default character encoding by which it validates and decodes the contents of string literals in C source files?  Is this configurable?

Further, when linking the string data from string literals into the data section of the output does it have a default execution character encoding?  Is this configurable?

In any configuration is it possible to have a source character encoding that differs from the execution character encoding?  (That is will gcc ever transcode between character encodings?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know how well these options actually work (not using them atm; I still prefer treating string literals as 'ASCII only', since localized strings come from external files anyway so it's mostly things like format strings or filenames), but they have added options like

```
-fexec-charset=charset
Set the execution character set, used for string and character constants. The default
is UTF-8. charset can be any encoding supported by the system's iconv library routine. 

-fwide-exec-charset=charset
Set the wide execution character set, used for wide string and character constants.
The default is UTF-32 or UTF-16, whichever corresponds to the width of wchar_t. As
with -fexec-charset, charset can be any encoding supported by the system's iconv
library routine; however, you will have problems with encodings that do not fit
exactly in wchar_t.

-finput-charset=charset
Set the input character set, used for translation from the character set of the
input file to the source character set used by GCC. If the locale does not specify,
or GCC cannot get this information from the locale, the default is UTF-8. This can
be overridden by either the locale or this command line option. Currently the command
line option takes precedence if there's a conflict. charset can be any encoding
supported by the system's iconv library routine.
```

Comment: I wonder if when the src and exec encoding is the default UTF-8, it actually validates the string literal as well-formed UTF-8 and raises an error if it contains invalid byte sequences - or whether it just lets the invalid bytes pass through.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I would also be very interested in this.  Did you ever determine if it performs this validation?

Comment: @alrav since this is something that's not defined by the standard, it's probably free to change from one compiler version to the next. I wouldn't trust an answer someone came up with 10 years ago.